# how to save/load data to n xml file

Tags: c#

i'm trying to load and save my data in my datagrid to an xml file using Singleton Design.

i have created

```
    public class DataProvider
{
    private static DataProvider singletonInstance = new DataProvider();
    private ObservablePerson Person;

    /// <summary>
    /// Private constructor
    /// </summary>
    private DataProvider()
    {
    }

    public static DataProvider GetInstance()
    {
        if (singletonInstance == null)
            singletonInstance = new DataProvider();

        return singletonInstance;
    }



    public bool SaveToXml(List<Person> PersonsList)
    {

        return false;
    }

    public List<Person> LoadFromX()
    {
        return new List<Person>() { new Person() { name= "jhon" } };
    }

}
```

}

and this is the object i want to save

```
[Serializable]
public class ObservablePerson : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();}
```

and i also created a view model form from person.
what should i do to save those data in my datagrid in a xml file .
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read an XML file using XmlTextReader and call Read method to read its node one by one until the end of file.

```
using System;  
using System.Xml;  
namespace ReadXml1 {  
    class Class1 {  
        static void Main(string[] args) {  
            // Create an isntance of XmlTextReader and call Read method to read the file  
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\books.xml");  
            textReader.Read();  
            // If the node has value  
            while (textReader.Read()) {  
                // Move to fist element  
                textReader.MoveToElement();  
                Console.WriteLine("XmlTextReader Properties Test");  
                Console.WriteLine("===================");  
                // Read this element's properties and display them on console  
                Console.WriteLine("Name:" + textReader.Name);  
                Console.WriteLine("Base URI:" + textReader.BaseURI);  
                Console.WriteLine("Local Name:" + textReader.LocalName);  
                Console.WriteLine("Attribute Count:" + textReader.AttributeCount.ToString());  
                Console.WriteLine("Depth:" + textReader.Depth.ToString());  
                Console.WriteLine("Line Number:" + textReader.LineNumber.ToString());  
                Console.WriteLine("Node Type:" + textReader.NodeType.ToString());  
                Console.WriteLine("Attribute Count:" + textReader.Value.ToString());  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

and for creating and save to XML file:

```
using System;  
using System.Xml;  
namespace ReadingXML2 {  
    class Class1 {  
        static void Main(string[] args) {  
            // Create a new file in C:\\ dir  
            XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\myXmFile.xml", null);  
            // Opens the document  
            textWriter.WriteStartDocument();  
            // Write comments  
            textWriter.WriteComment("First Comment XmlTextWriter Sample Example");  
            textWriter.WriteComment("myXmlFile.xml in root dir");  
            // Write first element  
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("Student");  
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("r", "RECORD", "urn:record");  
            // Write next element  
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("Name", "");  
            textWriter.WriteString("Student");  
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();  
            // Write one more element  
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("Address", "");  
            textWriter.WriteString("Colony");  
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();  
            // WriteChars  
            char[] ch = new char[3];  
            ch[0] = 'a';  
            ch[1] = 'r';  
            ch[2] = 'c';  
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("Char");  
            textWriter.WriteChars(ch, 0, ch.Length);  
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();  
            // Ends the document.  
            textWriter.WriteEndDocument();  
            // close writer  
            textWriter.Close();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: why should i create a new classes? i already implemented a DataProvider Class which has two methods for saving and loading to a xml file using singleton pattern design

Comment: You no longer need to create any new class. This is just an example which can help you how to implement it to your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use **Xml** and **Xml.Serialization**:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

On your singleton, implements

```
public static List<T> LoadFromXml<T>(string path, string fileName)
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    var xmlText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
    return (List<T>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlText));
}

public static bool SaveToXml<T>(List<T> list, string path, string fileName)
{
    var xmlText = Serialize<T>(list);
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, fileName), xmlText);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }            
}

private static string Serialize<T>(List<T> list)
{
    if (list == null || !list.Any())
        return string.Empty;

    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, list);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Using generic T, we can use the same methods to save other types of records

To call:

```
var person1 = new Person()
{
    name = "jhon",
};

var person2 = new Person()
{
    name = "another jhon",
};

var personList = new List<Person>();
personList.Add(person1);
personList.Add(person2);
var pathXml = @"C:\testes\xml";
var fileName = "persons.xml";
var dataProvider = DataProvider.GetInstance();
var itsSaved = dataProvider.SaveToXml<Person>(personList, pathXml, fileName);
var persons = dataProvider.LoadFromXml<Person>(pathXml, fileName);
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers

Comment: thaaank you so much

Comment: English is not my mother language and I am a little afraid of the technical terms. 
I also thought it was a 'readable code', 'question just asking for a code fix'.
But thanks for the information.
I'll just be on the stackoverflow of my language.
Regards.